# ForeignKey and form submission

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that is many-to-one with users.  But when I submit a form based on that model, I am not correctly providing the user.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    """Things."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    salt = models.IntegerField()
    # [...]

class GenerateThingForm(ModelForm):
    """A form for registering a new Thing."""
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = (...)    # There are some, but it would distract here
```

The view says this:

```
@login_required()
def register_thing(request):
    """Register Thing."""
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = GenerateThingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.salt = random.getrandbits(32)
            # Apparently I need to specify form.user.
            # Same result if just request.user
            form.user = User.objects.get(request.user)
            form.save()   # Oh, no!  'user_id' is null!
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the user or salt on the form instance, it has no idea what to do with it. Set it on the Thing that is generated from `form.save`.

```
thing = form.save(commit=False)
thing.salt = whatever
thing.user = myuser
thing.save()
```